# Why an `Arc<Mutex<dyn MyTrait>>` gets automatically the static lifetime?

Tags: rust

In this simple example, `renderer` is having the type `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<(dyn Renderer + 'static)>>`. This is a problem for me on my code right now, and I don't know why it happens.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub type OnConsume = Arc<dyn Fn() -> Option<u32> + Send + Sync>;

pub trait Renderer {
    fn set_on_consume(&mut self, f: OnConsume);
}
pub struct Stream {
    pub renderer: Arc<Mutex<dyn Renderer>>,
}

fn main() {}
```

Why `Arc<Mutex<dyn MyTrait>>` has static lifetime?

Comment: Take a look at the book section about [trait object lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that the struct `Stream` does not have any lifetimes attached to it, so there are no restrictions on how long it can live.

In the worst case scenario, `Stream` could have a lifetime of `'static` and since all of its fields must last that long, `dyn Renderer` must always assume this worst case scenario to be true.

We can however add an explicit lifetime to `Stream` to indicate that its lifetime is restricted to that of `dyn Renderer`. This way the compiler knows they must have the same lifetime and will correctly match it to your use case.

```rust
pub struct Stream<'a> {
    pub renderer: Arc<Mutex<dyn Renderer + 'a>>,
}
```